# using HTML/CSS with Headway Widget

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add the Headway Widget (https://headway.gitbooks.io/docs/content/widget.html) to our corporate BI website to publish changelog information. I used the documentation available at https://headway.gitbooks.io/docs/content/widget.html to create a simple HTML document, but I can't get the widget to show up in my page. I would appreciate any help I can get to figure out the issue.

It should work as follows:
https://gmelius.com/ - notice the Headway Widget on the News menu item.
https://jsfiddle.net/ - notice the Headway Widget on the top right corner of the page.

My changelog is available at https://headwayapp.co/teksystems-changelog

Here is what my HTML code looks like so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var HW_config = {
  selector: "h2",
  account: "5JVROJ"
};
</script>
<script async src="//cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>
<a href="">News</a>
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check is there any errors in console?

Comment: @FastSnail aha, I see the following error - Failed to load resource: file://cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @FastSnail ok, what would be the absolute url? the two other sites are using <script async src="//cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js"></script>. So, I am a little confused.

Comment: are you hosting your html files in cdn.headwayapp.co/ ?basically you are not adding js file correctly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine on code pen. Are you trying to add it locally first on a development site ? Because when I view it locally it fails when embedding the widget which is really just a link to the template for your account.

Here it is in code pen:
[codepen.io/Riddell/pen/KzGGPq](http://codepen.io/Riddell/pen/KzGGPq)

```
<h2><a href="">News</a></h2>
<script>
    var HW_config = {
        account: "5JVROJ",
        selector: "h2"
    };
</script>
<script async src="https://cdn.headwayapp.co/widget.js"></script>
```

You could try running local WAMP/MAMP server to test locally.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to add it locally first. I will try running it on a web server.